# Stack level too deep when using Rails generate scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting the below stack error when trying to run the above from the Ruby on Rails Tutorial

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in ': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Was having another issue previously which lead me to making the app again from scratch, but now I can't solve this

results should invoke and create what looks like some scaffold files

Answer (score 2):

From that error message, you seem to be using Rails 4.2.2 and Ruby 2.6.3. Using those two versions together is not supported.

Rails 4.2 only supports Ruby versions up to 2.4.5. See the [travis.yml](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/.travis.yml#L25-L31) on the 4.2 branch to see what's supported.

Try either downgrading your Ruby version or upgrading your Rails version so that they're compatible.

Comment: Rails 4.x is no longer supported on current versions of Ruby and is a bad place to start building apps anyway as a lot has changed since. Use 5.2 if you can.

Comment: Thanks, some how I managed to switch to an older version of the book, because I finished the earlier chapter with no issue, I didn't notice. I did see in the above roots, that that rails 5 was being used, but still couldn't confirm the issue at the time.